# Android SmsManager Why I get the Sms From destination number

Tags: android, smsmanager

I used the SmsManager to send Sms to destination phone. The problem is that somehow two Sms sent: One Sms to the destination phone, which is fine, but also I get the exact Sms from the destination number in my phone.

The code:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(destPhoneNumber, null, "Message", null, null);
```

How is it possible my phone get the message I send to destination number from the destination number itself?

Comment: Please post your full code @Uziel Davidi

Comment: Where are you seeing this second, unwanted message? In your own app, or in other SMS apps?

Comment: My phone gets the SMS I sent from the app to other phone number

Comment: Please post all of your code related to SMS, and screenshots showing the sent and received messages.